# GLSL layout std140 padding dilemma

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, uniform

I have the following uniform buffer:

```
layout(std140) uniform Light
{
    vec4  AmbientLight;
    vec4  LightIntensity;
    vec3  LightPosition;
    float LightAttenuation;
};
```

I have some issues when buffering the data and the padding I need to add. I have read the http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321552624/downloads/0321552628_AppL.pdf which says I have to add an extra 4 bytes at the end of the vec3 for padding - so I will upload a total of 13 bytes for 'Light'. When I do that however, 'LightAttenuation' gets the value I padded on 'LightPosition', rather than one byte ahead, so I get the correct values in the shader when I do NOT pad. Why is this?

Comment: "*I have read the [PDF] which says*" Who cares what it says? [The OpenGL specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/) is the primary source; everything else is secondary. And the description of the std140 layout is not as unreadable as people might say.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See section 7.6.2.2 of the OpenGL spec for the details, but basically, `std140` layout says that each variable will be laid out immediately after the previous variable with enough padding added for the alignment required for the variable's type.  `vec3`  and `vec4` both require 16-byte alignment and are 12 and 16 bytes respectively.  `float` requires 4 byte alignment and has 4 byte size.  So with `std140` layout, `LightPosition` will get 16 byte alignment so will always end at an address that is 12 mod 16.  Since this is 4-byte aligned, no extra padding will be inserted before `LightAttenuation`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually yes, openGL will treat a vec3 as an vec4. But AFAIK in this case it appends the float LightAttenuation to the vec3 LightPosition - forming an overall vec4 (its some kind of optimization, done by the glsl compiler).
The whole structure will be of size 3x vec4.

Try out using a vec3 or vec4 for LightAttenuation.